# Unable to set "no index" property in Spartacus angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

I tried to change page specific meta tag as `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` and also I am having robot tags in pages api. But it's not changed in page still it shows `<meta name="robots" content="INDEX, FOLLOW">`. Below image for the reference of API returning values:

[image: pages api]

Kindly give some suggestions even I have customized the PageMetaResolver. I don't know how to handle this issue.

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: If you are using Chrome and have Redux, maybe you can check cms page state to see whether `robots` have `["INDEX", "NOFOLLOW"]`. If yes, then the meta should be `<meta name="robots" content="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">`. No need to change the `PageMetaResolver`.

Comment: @WeizhengGao can you share some code as an example?

Comment: In `OccCmsPageNormalizer`, there is function `normalizeRobots`, which checks pageRobots: (such as: `case Occ.PageRobots.INDEX_NOFOLLOW: robots.push(PageRobotsMeta.INDEX); robots.push(PageRobotsMeta.NOFOLLOW); break;`.)

And in `BasePageMetaResolver`, function `resolveRobots()` just returns the Observable of robots which is got from the previous nomalizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own customized normalizer. For example, you can provide a new custom normalizer as explained in here https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#providing-custom-converters.

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: CMS_PAGE_NORMALIZER,
      useClass: YourCustomNormalizer,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

You can copy paste what was done in the source code (OccCmsPageNormalizer), and change what is being pushed in the switch case, such as

```
   case Occ.PageRobots.INDEX_NOFOLLOW:
          robots.push('noindex'); -- or any of your already created custom enums
          break;
```

Similarly, you can extend `OccCmsPageNormalizer` and override normalizeRobots function to change the behavior to your needs

Comment: @BrainGj since I using Spartacus 2.1.7 version and I tried to achieve the custom normalizer its shows a lot of models difference, Error in console